# Applying Modulo in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module mod_dp_32bit (
    input wire clk,
    input wire rst,
    input wire start,
    input wire [31:0] A,
    input wire [31:0] B,
    output wire done,
    output wire [31:0] result
);

reg [31:0] temp;

always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if (rst) begin
        temp <= 32'b0;
    end 
     else if (start) begin
        temp <= A;
    end 
     else if (temp >= B) begin
        temp <= temp - B;
    end 
     else begin
        temp <= temp; 
    end
end


assign done = (temp < B);
assign result = temp;

endmodule

`timescale 1ns/1ns

    module Mod32_TB;
      
      reg clk;
      reg rst;
      reg start;
      reg [31:0] A;
      reg [31:0] B;
      wire done;
      wire [31:0] result;
    
      // Instantiate mod_dp_32bit module
      mod_dp_32bit uut (
        .clk(clk),
        .rst(rst),
        .start(start),
        .A(A),
        .B(B),
        .done(done),
        .result(result)
      );
    
      // Clock generation
      initial begin
        clk = 0;
        forever #5 clk = ~clk;
      end
    
      // Test Case 1: A mod B
      initial begin
        // Initialize inputs
        rst = 0;
        A = 100;
        B = 7;
        start = 0;
    
        // Release reset
        #10 rst = 0;
    
        // Test Case 1: A mod B
        #5 start = 1;
        #100 start = 0;
        #100;
    
        // Display result
        $display("Test Case 1 Result: A mod B = %d", result);
    
        // End simulation
        $stop;
      end
    
    endmodule
```

I'm trying to write a module in Verilog that performs a modulo operation with a 32-bit operand. The module operates as follows:

```
temp = a;

while(temp >= b)
     temp = temp - b;
result = temp;
```

This code incorrectly calculates modulo operations such as 100 mod 7 and 255 mod 7 when it is intended to compute modulo operations like 95 mod 12 and 5 mod 10. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code does:

- When start is 1, you set the result to the A input every clock cycle.
- When start is 0, you subtract B from the result every cycle until the result is less than or equal to B.
- For the values of A and B in the testbench, the result would be 2 if you let the simulation run long enough (at least 13 cycles after start goes low).

You say you want it to calculate the modulo, but you do not say what result you expect.  You could just use the Verilog modulo operator: `%`

You should dump waveforms and view the signal values as a function of time.  It is usually insufficient to debug code only using `$display` statements.